# How to capture live camera frames in RGB with DirectShow

Tags: visual-c++, camera, directshow, video-capture, augmented-reality

I'm implementing live video capture through DirectShow for live processing and display. (Augmented Reality app).

I can access the pixels easily enough, but it seems I can't get the SampleGrabber to provide RGB data. The device (an iSight -- running VC++ Express in VMWare) only reports MEDIASUBTYPE_YUY2.

After extensive Googling, I still can't figure out whether DirectShow is supposed to provide built-in color space conversion for this sort of thing. Some sites report that there is no YUV<->RGB conversion built in, [others](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/directx/directshow/article.php/c9551/) report that you just have to call SetMediaType on your ISampleGrabber with an RGB subtype.

Any advice is greatly appreciated, I'm going nuts on this one. Code provided below. Please note that

- The code works, except that it doesn't provide RGB data
- I'm aware that I can implement my own conversion filter, but this is not feasible because I'd have to anticipate every possible device format, and this is a relatively small project

  ```
  // Playback
  IGraphBuilder *pGraphBuilder = NULL;
  ICaptureGraphBuilder2 *pCaptureGraphBuilder2 = NULL;
  IMediaControl *pMediaControl = NULL;
  IBaseFilter *pDeviceFilter = NULL;
  IAMStreamConfig *pStreamConfig = NULL;
  BYTE *videoCaps = NULL;
  AM_MEDIA_TYPE **mediaTypeArray = NULL;

  // Device selection
  ICreateDevEnum *pCreateDevEnum = NULL;
  IEnumMoniker *pEnumMoniker = NULL;
  IMoniker *pMoniker = NULL;
  ULONG nFetched = 0;

  HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

  // Create CreateDevEnum to list device
  hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICreateDevEnum, (PVOID *)&pCreateDevEnum);
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  // Create EnumMoniker to list devices 
  hr = pCreateDevEnum->CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, &pEnumMoniker, 0);
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  pEnumMoniker->Reset();

  // Find desired device
  while (pEnumMoniker->Next(1, &pMoniker, &nFetched) == S_OK) 
  {
    IPropertyBag *pPropertyBag;
    TCHAR devname[256];

    // bind to IPropertyBag
    hr = pMoniker->BindToStorage(0, 0, IID_IPropertyBag, (void **)&pPropertyBag);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
      pMoniker->Release();
      continue;
    }

    VARIANT varName;
    VariantInit(&varName);
    HRESULT hr = pPropertyBag->Read(L"DevicePath", &varName, 0);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
      pMoniker->Release();
      pPropertyBag->Release();
      continue;
    }

    char devicePath[DeviceInfo::STRING_LENGTH_MAX] = "";

    wcstombs(devicePath, varName.bstrVal, DeviceInfo::STRING_LENGTH_MAX);

    if (strcmp(devicePath, deviceId) == 0)
    {
      // Bind Moniker to Filter
      pMoniker->BindToObject(0, 0, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&pDeviceFilter);

      break;
    }

    pMoniker->Release();
    pPropertyBag->Release();
  }

  if (pDeviceFilter == NULL) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  // Create sample grabber
  IBaseFilter *pGrabberF = NULL;
  hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SampleGrabber, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&pGrabberF);
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  hr = pGrabberF->QueryInterface(IID_ISampleGrabber, (void**)&pGrabber);
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  // Create FilterGraph
  hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph,
  NULL,
  CLSCTX_INPROC,
  IID_IGraphBuilder,
  (LPVOID *)&pGraphBuilder);
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  // create CaptureGraphBuilder2
  hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2, (LPVOID *)&pCaptureGraphBuilder2);
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  // set FilterGraph
  hr = pCaptureGraphBuilder2->SetFiltergraph(pGraphBuilder);
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  // get MediaControl interface
  hr = pGraphBuilder->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (LPVOID *)&pMediaControl);
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  // Add filters
  hr = pGraphBuilder->AddFilter(pDeviceFilter, L"Device Filter");
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  hr = pGraphBuilder->AddFilter(pGrabberF, L"Sample Grabber");
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  // Set sampe grabber options
  AM_MEDIA_TYPE mt;
  ZeroMemory(&mt, sizeof(AM_MEDIA_TYPE));
  mt.majortype = MEDIATYPE_Video;
  mt.subtype = MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB32;
  hr = pGrabber->SetMediaType(&mt);
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  hr = pGrabber->SetOneShot(FALSE);
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  hr = pGrabber->SetBufferSamples(TRUE);
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  // Get stream config interface
  hr = pCaptureGraphBuilder2->FindInterface(NULL, &MEDIATYPE_Video, pDeviceFilter, IID_IAMStreamConfig, (void **)&pStreamConfig);
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  int streamCapsCount = 0, capsSize, bestFit = -1, bestFitPixelDiff = 1000000000, desiredPixelCount = _width * _height,
  bestFitWidth = 0, bestFitHeight = 0;

  float desiredAspectRatio = (float)_width / (float)_height;

  hr = pStreamConfig->GetNumberOfCapabilities(&streamCapsCount, &capsSize);
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  videoCaps = (BYTE *)malloc(capsSize * streamCapsCount);
  mediaTypeArray = (AM_MEDIA_TYPE **)malloc(sizeof(AM_MEDIA_TYPE *) * streamCapsCount);

  for (int i = 0; i < streamCapsCount; i++)
  {
    hr = pStreamConfig->GetStreamCaps(i, &mediaTypeArray[i], videoCaps + capsSize * i);
    if (FAILED(hr)) continue;

    VIDEO_STREAM_CONFIG_CAPS *currentVideoCaps = (VIDEO_STREAM_CONFIG_CAPS *)(videoCaps + capsSize * i);

    int closestWidth = MAX(currentVideoCaps->MinOutputSize.cx, MIN(currentVideoCaps->MaxOutputSize.cx, width));
    int closestHeight = MAX(currentVideoCaps->MinOutputSize.cy, MIN(currentVideoCaps->MaxOutputSize.cy, height));

    int pixelDiff = ABS(desiredPixelCount - closestWidth * closestHeight);

    if (pixelDiff < bestFitPixelDiff && ABS(desiredAspectRatio - (float)closestWidth / (float)closestHeight) < 0.1f)
    {
      bestFit = i;
      bestFitPixelDiff = pixelDiff;
      bestFitWidth = closestWidth;
      bestFitHeight = closestHeight;
    }
  }

  if (bestFit == -1) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  AM_MEDIA_TYPE *mediaType;
  hr = pStreamConfig->GetFormat(&mediaType);
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  VIDEOINFOHEADER *videoInfoHeader = (VIDEOINFOHEADER *)mediaType->pbFormat;
  videoInfoHeader->bmiHeader.biWidth = bestFitWidth;
  videoInfoHeader->bmiHeader.biHeight = bestFitHeight;
  //mediaType->subtype = MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB32;
  hr = pStreamConfig->SetFormat(mediaType);
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  pStreamConfig->Release();
  pStreamConfig = NULL;

  free(videoCaps);
  videoCaps = NULL;
  free(mediaTypeArray);
  mediaTypeArray = NULL;

  // Connect pins
  IPin *pDeviceOut = NULL, *pGrabberIn = NULL;

  if (FindPin(pDeviceFilter, PINDIR_OUTPUT, 0, &pDeviceOut) && FindPin(pGrabberF, PINDIR_INPUT, 0, &pGrabberIn))
  {
    hr = pGraphBuilder->Connect(pDeviceOut, pGrabberIn);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;
  }
  else
  {
    goto ReleaseDataAndFail;
  }

  // start playing
  hr = pMediaControl->Run();
  if (FAILED(hr)) goto ReleaseDataAndFail;

  hr = pGrabber->GetConnectedMediaType(&mt);

  // Set dimensions
  width = bestFitWidth;
  height = bestFitHeight;
  _width = bestFitWidth;
  _height = bestFitHeight;

  // Allocate pixel buffer
  pPixelBuffer = (unsigned *)malloc(width * height * 4);

  // Release objects
  pGraphBuilder->Release();
  pGraphBuilder = NULL;
  pEnumMoniker->Release();
  pEnumMoniker = NULL;
  pCreateDevEnum->Release();
  pCreateDevEnum = NULL;

  return true;
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stock colour space converter does not support YUY2 to RGB conversion. However, there are a number of apps and devices that install a converter of some sort, and if this is properly registered, dshow will use it automatically. That's why some people report that it just works. (of course some devices offer RGB, so no conversion is needed in those cases).

You can download a freely-available YUV conversion filter, "yuvxfm" from [YUV Transform (at the bottom of the page)](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/downloads.htm). Register this on your system and it should allow capture in any reasonable RGB or YUV format.

G

Comment: Thanks a lot for your informative response. I tried adding an yuvxfm filter between the device and the sample grabber, which worked. However, I also found that if it also works without. I tried unregistering yuvxfm and going directly from the device to the rgb sample grabber. I don't know why it didn't work before. I'm running on an almost fresh install of XP SP3. Also tried it on Windows 7, which also works.

So where is the YUY2 to RGB transformation happening? Can I depend on this?

Comment: Yes. Its the AviDecompressor, which supports the YUY2 FourCC. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375464%28v=VS.85%29.aspx for a list of filters which are provided.

Comment: The AviDecompressor is a wrapper for Video for Windows codecs. It's likely that you have a VfW codec installed that does YUY2 conversion, but this will be system-dependent. The Avi Decompressor wrapper filter may be present without the YUY2 support on some systems.